# How Does One Get the "Road to 80" Buff?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I recently reached level 60 on the free trial of the game, and have been loving it so far. I purchased the complete edition of the game right after finishing the Heavensward main story. I have been seeing many players around the game with new characters with a buff called "The Road to 80" which significantly increases exp until 80. Is the buff only obtainable on new characters after buying the game, or is there some way to get this buff while I play through the MSQ and catch up to Endwalker?

Answer (score 4):

Some worlds with low population can be designated as "preferred worlds". Characters created on those worlds get the Road to 80 exp buff.

[Source](https://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Experience#The_Road_to_80)